# Has Prettify implementation been updated?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Noticed that VBScript samples are coming up different now, has there been some change to the styling of the markdown syntax highlighting?

```vb
Function Hello()
  'This is a comment
  Call MsgBox("Hello World")
End Function

Call Hello()
```

Strings used to be maroon, but now come out green which I struggling to adjust to.

Comment: @bluefeet I didn't get this until about 1 hour ago I guess caching?, but colours have been fine all day. I did search first but nothing came back.

Comment: If you see the answer, you'll notice it was updated about an hour ago.

Comment: @bluefeet that's fine I was just explaining why I posted the question, didn't disagree with the action taken.